# iOS Share Sheet: How to share CSV data in a way Numbers app and Excel are offered for import?

Tags: ios, ios-sharesheet

I try to use CSV data via the iOS share sheet. My problem: The share sheet does not offer the apps „Apple Numbers“ or „Microsoft Excel“ for import! If I use „Save to files“ in the share sheet first and share this saved file via Files App later, Excel and Numbers are displayed as possible targets and accept the data.

I already tried many different methods to provide my data, but I was not able to get Numbers and Excel appear as targets in the share sheet.

Any idea how this can be achieved?

Three ways in which I tried to provide the data are shown below:

Providing CSV as Data:

```swift
private var dataItem:NSItemProvider?{
    guard let data = csvData else {return nil}
    let item = NSItemProvider(item: data as NSSecureCoding, typeIdentifier: UTType.commaSeparatedText.identifier)
    item.suggestedName = "Test" + ".csv"

    return item
}
```

Saving CSV to temporary file and providing an URL:

```swift
private var fileURLItem:NSItemProvider?{
    let name = "Test" + Date().description

    let fileManager = FileManager.default
    guard let cacheDirectory = try? fileManager.url(for: .cachesDirectory, in: .userDomainMask, appropriateFor: nil, create: true),
    let data = csvData else {
        return nil
    }
    let fileLocation = cacheDirectory.appendingPathComponent("\(name).csv")
    try? data.write(to: fileLocation, options: .atomicWrite)

//  return NSItemProvider(item: fileLocation as NSSecureCoding, typeIdentifier: UTType.fileURL.identifier) // either way doesn't work
    return NSItemProvider(contentsOf: fileLocation)
    }
```

A combination of both, trying to mimic the types „Files“ app offers to the share sheet:

```swift
class Exporter:NSObject, NSItemProviderWriting{
    static var writableTypeIdentifiersForItemProvider: [String] = [UTType.commaSeparatedText.identifier, UTType.fileURL.identifier]
    
    func loadData(withTypeIdentifier typeIdentifier: String,
                  forItemProviderCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping (Data?, Error?) -> Void) -> Progress?{
        
        switch typeIdentifier{
        case UTType.commaSeparatedText.identifier:
            completionHandler(sampleCSV.data(using: .utf8)!, nil)
        case UTType.fileURL.identifier:
            completionHandler(fileURL!.dataRepresentation, nil)
        default:
            completionHandler(nil, ExporterError.unknownUTI)
        }
        
        return nil
    }
```

The third way doe not work at all and result in

> Could not instantiate class NSURL. Error: Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=4864 "A URL cannot be instantiated from a representation of type “public.url” even after treating it as a string." UserInfo={NSDebugDescription=A URL cannot be instantiated from a representation of type “public.url” even after treating it as a string., NSUnderlyingError=0x6000018c20d0 {Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=4864 "The URL archive of type “public.url” contains invalid data." UserInfo={NSDebugDescription=The URL archive of type “public.url” contains invalid data.}}}

printed to console. This error can't even be found via a Google search.

Comment: Here is some code from one of my apps; I pass the csv data as a string, but you could use data. https://gist.github.com/paulw11/82f0a7895b9b03349ad2dd7ee15a4092

Comment: Interesting! You use ```UIActivityItemSource``` instead of ```NSItemProvider```. Does anyone know the difference between the two approaches?
Unfortunately I tried using ```UIActivityItemSource``` and Numbers and Excel are still not offered as targets on the Share Sheet. Are they offered in your example?

Comment: They are, but only under "more..", "suggestions"

Comment: Thanks, unfortunately they aren't for me.
Could you please tell me how you setup your UIActivityViewController?

Comment: I added that function to the gist. Nothing special.

Comment: **Thanks** to your help, I was now able to get my code working.
But I still don't know why there are multiply ways to present data to the share sheet and only one specific way works with Numbers and Excel. All the other ways work for everything else.

Comment: According to the documentation, `NSItemProvider` is for drag and drop